# Java - How to Mock impl via using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have this repository created in my class as such:

```
    private static ModuleRepository repository = new ModuleRepository();
```

its called via:

```
  repository.isModuleCached(moduleType,taxModuleInfo.getModuleYear(), taxModuleInfo.getModuleVersion()
```

However when I try to mock it in my test class, I cannot actually return the mocked result I want, instead it calls the actual repository, as if my mockito call is ignored.

My Test case setup includes:

```
@Mock
private ModuleRepository repository;
```

my Test classs:

```
when(repository.isModuleCached(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(resp);
```

The actualy repository in the class isn't autowired, it's instantiated, maybe that could be it?

Comment: `The actualy repository in the class isn't autowired, it's instantiated, maybe that could be it?`. Yes, avoid doing that. Spring exists exactly so that you don't need to do this kind of instantiations.

Comment: Could you please post your code? I think you didn't inject your mocked repository into your class

Comment: the new ModuleRepository(); is from a library and imported as static, there's no bean def if using @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

Use @MockBean instead of @Mock. It tells Spring Boot that you're mocking an autowired bean.

```
@MockBean
private ModuleRepository repository;
```

Your test will also have to be annotated with @SpringBootTest

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans

Answer (score 0):

If `ModuleRepository` is from a library you don't control, then define a Spring Bean for it as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class RepoConfig {
    @Bean
    public ModuleRepository getModuleRepository() {
        return new ModuleRepository();
    }
}
```

Now you can inject it as a Spring Bean using `@Autowired`, or better yet, using construction injection.

After you do this, you can use `@MockBean` in your test:

```java
@MockBean
private ModuleRepository repository;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize all of your non-bean mock objects during the test setup

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `when(xxx.xxx()).thenReturn(xxx)`.

Try `doReturn(xxx).when(xxx).xxx()` instead.

Here is an example:
`doReturn(resp).when(repository).isModuleCached(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());`

Also, the repository value is not injected.
Here is your example code:
`private static ModuleRepository repository = new ModuleRepository();`

Because you are initializing the variable by hand,
you must replace it with a Mock object, by hand, using Reflection.

Spring provides `ReflectionTestUtils` which will help.